# Python schedule different part of code with different times

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script which has two sections:

- a first section where it calls an api query (i want to run this two times a day)
- the second section where it makes other functions given the results of the first call (i want to run this every minute)

I want to call the api request only two times a day because the results won't vary over time and i want the second part of the code to run every minute, how can i accomplish this in python with a cron job which runs the script every minute?

Comment: Use two seperate cron jobs and two sepreate communicating scripts.

Comment: how can i pass the results from the first to the second?

Comment: The first cron job writes to a file, the second job reads from that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it could be one script which is triggered with different options to reflect first section and second section. Serialization of the data into a file at a temporary space would be the option for data exchange between both calls.

I've written informal code for you, i have not checked if it is working or correct, just to get an idea, what you can do:

```
import requests  # do pip install requests
import sys

headers = {'accept': 'application/json'}

def get_data_from_api():
    response = requests.get(url="http://foobar", headers=headers)
    with open('/tmp/mysaved_data', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(response.json())

def do_fancy_stuff_with_json():
    with open('/tmp/mysaved_data', 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines(f)

    # Do the second section stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 0:  # more than one param -> call the second function
        do_fancy_stuff_with_json()
    else:
        get_data_from_api()
```

In cron you would then define two jobs:

```
0 5 * * 1 /usr/bin/python myscript.py
/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python myscript.py dummy
```